# how to display the progress bar of a function in an APP(GUI using tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to display an progress bar to indicate to the user that something is happening. I want to display it when i click on CLASSIFY (as it shown in the image) to start a function, then the bar will disappear at the end of the function.

This is the function:

```py
pbar = ttk.Progressbar(gui1, orient="horizontal", length=300)
pbar.place(x=500, y=120)

def Classifyall():
    pbar.start(15)

    table = BeautifulTable()
    table.column_headers = ["File Name", "File Format"]
    directory_path = '/home/.../All files/*'
    file_list = glob.glob(directory_path)
    for file in file_list:
        filepath, file_extention = os.path.splitext(file)
        filename = filepath.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
        table.append_row([filename, file_extention])
    tx.insert(END, table)
    pbar.stop()
```

here i created a menu bar who contains functions

```py
tool_menu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Tool", menu=tool_menu)
tool_menu.add_command(label="Classify", command=Classifyall)
```

[image: the image]

Comment: how did you try to implement the progress bar?

Comment: it tried  this:                                                                                                                                                         import time
from progressbar import ProgressBar
pbar = ProgressBar()
def job():
        Code ....

Comment: [edit] question and include your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to run a time-consuming task in a thread, otherwise it will make tkinter application not responding.

I use another function `start_classification()` to be executed after menu item `Classify` is selected.

Inside that function:

- create a progress bar in *indeterminate* mode
- start the progress bar animation
- create a tkinter variable to hold the result from `Classifyall()`
- start a child thread to execute `Classifyall()`
- wait for the child thread to complete
- destroy the progress bar
- update the text box with the result from `Classifyall()`

```py
import threading
from tkinter import ttk
...

# added argument var (a tkinter StringVar)
def Classifyall(var):
    table = BeautifulTable()
    table.column_headers = ["File Name", "File Format"]
    directory_path = '/home/.../All files/*'
    file_list = glob.glob(directory_path)
    for file in file_list:
        filepath, file_extention = os.path.splitext(file)
        filename = filepath.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
        table.append_row([filename, file_extention])

    # note that it is not safe to update tkinter widget in a child thread
    # so use the passed tkinter variable to save the result instead
    var.set(table)

def start_classification():
    # create a progress bar and start the animation
    pbar = ttk.Progressbar(gui1, orient='horizontal', length=300, mode='indeterminate')
    pbar.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')
    pbar.start()

    var = StringVar() # hold the result from Classifyall()
    # execute Classifyall() in a child thread
    threading.Thread(target=Classifyall, args=(var,)).start()
    # wait for the child thread to complete
    tx.wait_variable(var)

    pbar.destroy()
    tx.insert(END, var.get())

...

tool_menu = Menu(menu)
tool_menu.add_command(label='Classify', command=start_classification) # call start_classification() instead
menu.add_cascade(label='Tool', menu=tool_menu)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tkinter.ttk.Progressbar`:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

w = tkinter.Tk()
pbar = ttk.Progressbar(w)
```

It uses two ways of making it "progress":

**1: Automatic Progression**

Using the `start()` and `stop()` methods, you can have the progress bar progress all by itself at a certain speed. An argument can be passed to `start()` that specifies the milliseconds between each update. So calling `pbar.start(50)` would progress the bar 1% every 50 milliseconds. Calling `stop()` stops the progress bar and resets its progress to 0%.

Note: once the progress bar is finished, you must call `stop()`, or it will reset to 0% and start progressing all over again.

**2: Manual Progression**

The progress bar can also be progressed manually by calling the `step()` method. An argument must be passed to `step()` that specifies the percent to progress. So, calling `pbar.step(35)` adds 35% to the progress of the progress bar. And yes, negative numbers are allowed as well: `pbar.step(-35)`.

Comment: i used this method(Automatic Progression) as it shown in the programme i edited it, but doesn't work

Comment: @DYAMB: Could you please be more specific as to *what* didn't work?